# Link-to class when not active

Tags: ember.js

I have a link to helper that generate a `<span>`. The `<span>` should:

1. have the class:"arrow open" when it is active.
2. have the class:"arrow" when it is NOT active.

   {{#link-to 'status' tagName="span" activeClass="arrow open"}}
   {{/link-to}}

**Question:** The point 1 is working with the use of the activeClass. However, I don't how to assign a class when the link-to helper is not active as per the point 2.

tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from [the guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/#toc_adding-additional-attributes-on-a-link):

```
{{#link-to 'status' tagName='span' class='arrow' activeClass='open'}} {{/link-to}}
```

The `class` property lets you set the class that will be present at all times.